# How can I encrypt email message by recipient's certificate?

Tags: java, encryption, jakarta-mail

I'm using `javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime` library for email digital signature and encryption.

I have checked some examples for email encryption from Internet, and they always use the public key which store in keystore. But I need to use the public key which store in recipient's certificate.

I know how to get public key from X.509 certificate.

```
CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("certFile.cer")));
Certificate cert = cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(fis);
Key pKey = cert.getPublicKey();
```

And I have a sample code for encryption eamil message by `javamail-crypto-bouncycastle-smime`.

```
EncryptionUtils smimeUtils = EncryptionManager.getEncryptionUtils(EncryptionManager.SMIME);
char[] smimePw = new String(_smimePw).toCharArray();
EncryptionKeyManager smimeKeyMgr = smimeUtils.createKeyManager();
smimeKeyMgr.loadPublicKeystore(new FileInputStream(_filepk12), smimePw);
Key smimeKey = smimeKeyMgr.getPublicKey(_alias);
MimeMessage smimeEncryptedMsg = smimeUtils.encryptMessage(session, message, smimeKey);
```

The problem is the sample code use pk12 public key, but what I have is X.509 public key which don't need password.

How can I encrypt email message by recipient's X.509 certificate?

Comment: Please try not to ask multiple questions in one post. What is your primary problem here - getting a public key from an X.509 certificate?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have edited the question.